# CSS @media only screen query not working under 360px

Tags: css, media-queries, spfx

I am trying to use CSS to style the mobile responsive Webpage.  When I resize chrome to 360px, the styles shows its detecting 432px.
When chrome is reduced to 320px, the content inside the li, div is empty.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
```

is added to the header section of the webpage

```
  //media query for mobile responsiveness
  @media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {
    .header {
      min-width: 100%;
      margin: 0px;
      text-align: left;
      font-size: 10px;
      font-weight: bold;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      // border: 1px solid red;
    }
    .container li div {
      padding: 5px 75px;
      margin: 0px;
      text-align: center;

      //border: 1px solid blue;
    }
  }
```

//code continues with different break points

```
  @media only screen and (max-width: 432px) {
    .header {
      min-width: 100%;
      margin: 0px;
      text-align: left;
      font-size: 10px;
      font-weight: bold;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
    }
    .container li div {
      padding: 5px 25px;
      margin: 3px;
      text-align: center;
      width: 90%;
      height: 100%;
      font-size: 16px;
      //border: 1px solid blue;
    }
  }
```

GIF indicating a 360px detected as 432px

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS `max-width: 432px` will effect any screen size under or equal to 432px. Screen size `360px` is less than `432px` therefore this rule will be applied.

CSS is *Cascading* so the latest rule will overwrite any earlier rules.

If this is the last CSS then it will overwrite any values previously set by - for example - `@media only screen and (max-width: 320px){ ...}`

The way to solve this is to set your CSS in order so that the largest CSS is at the top, and the smallest width set is at the bottom:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 720px) {
 ...
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
 ...
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
 ...
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 360px) {
 ...
}
```

If you decide to use `min-width` instead of `max-width` then obviously reverse the order of these media styles. The point is that the CSS will apply every style that fits the criteria and the *last one is the one that sticks!*. So The last one should be the final correct one; in this case